# How to use correctly use REGEXP_LIKE in a constraint

Tags: oracle, constraints

I want to use a constraint that requires the input to be 'SUB' followed by 4 digits. So far this is what ive got but its throws this error.

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptionsTable(
subID number PRIMARY KEY,
channelID number,
userID number,
subStartDate DATE NULL, 
subEndDate DATE NULL,
subCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT c_subCode (check REGEXP_LIKE(subCode,['SUB{3}[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
);

ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax issue in the `CHECK` constraint and your regex pattern needs a small change.

You need the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBSCRIPTIONSTABLE(
    SUBID          NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    CHANNELID      NUMBER,
    USERID         NUMBER,
    SUBSTARTDATE   DATE NULL,
    SUBENDDATE     DATE NULL,
    SUBCODE        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT     C_SUBCODE
CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE ( SUBCODE, '^(SUB)[0-9]{4}' ) ) ); -- changes here
```